# Xcode autocomplete crossed out?

Tags: xcode

Having trouble finding an explanation in the docs, would someone be kind enough to explain to me what the red crossed out coordinate means in the image below?

[image]

Comment: The objects in annotationList are custom annotation objects, subclass of NSObject which conform to the MKAnnotation protocol.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The crossed out options indicate deprecated methods, though I'm not sure how the compiler has decided what is deprecated given that it has no idea what class the object is. For example, `coordinate` is deprecated in `MKReverseGeocoder` as of iOS5, as is the whole class.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, As I mentioned the objects in annotationList conform to the MKAnnotation protocol of which coordinate is a required property.

Comment: In that case I wouldn't worry - if you cast the object returned from the array, I expect the coordinate won't show up as deprecated any more. The compiler is just guessing at the moment since it is dealing with an `id`.

Comment: Thank you jrturton, casting did remove the red underline. Much appreciated.